# How to hide Navigation Bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigationbar

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Comment: why are you taking navigation bar if you want to hide it?

Comment: also please write the question in standard format so it can be readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this to remove the navigation bar.

> ```
> (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
> { 
>     self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease]; 
>    // Override point for customization after application launch. 
>    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 
>    self.window.rootViewController = masterViewController; 
>    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; return YES;
> }
> ```

Comment: The problem's been resolved, thx

Answer (score 0):

Set the `navigationBarHidden` property to hide the navigationBar. For reference, see [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Add the below statement to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: Your answer did not solve the problem, but the answer thanks